# How to change colors in windows IE10 viewsource?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

How does one change the colors of the IE9,10 viewsource mode and within developer tools?
Is this possible at all?

Kind regards, mtness

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any way to change the colours in the in-built IE View Source window, but I've got a better suggestion. Since that window anyway is pretty worthless, you can simply replace it with a proper text/HTML editor of your choice. If it's small, powerful and yet loads fast (something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) perhaps), it will be *much* more helpful compared to the default viewer.

Just save the following as a .REG file, edit to include the full path to your favourite editor's EXE, then import and you should be good to go:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor\Editor Name]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor\Editor Name]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe"
```

Note: Tested only with IE9 so far (both 32 and 64-bit versions), not IE10. Absolutely no harm in trying though (changes can be easily reverted), so let me know if it works with IE10 as well.